# Java Slick 2D Collision Detection Methodology

Tags: java, design-patterns, api, collision

I have a collision detection for terrain setup (non-terrain is handled with a quadtree I implemented apart from this) and I was wondering how others have done it compared to mine and what I could learn from people's critiques here.

My map is stored in a 2D array of "GameSquare"s

```
public class GameSquare extends GameObject {
    private char tileLetter = 'W';
    private int row, col;
}
public boolean isPassable() {
    return tileLetter != 'W';
}
```

The row and col are the index in the 2D array.

The char corresponds to the graphic, my render checks the char and draws a Wall(W), Floor(O), or Door(X)

**The Player**
My player class gets track of the player in pixels. The speed and X,Y positions are all in exact pixels. I divide those measures by the width or height of the tile graphics I use and truncate it; in order to find the corresponding array cell that the player is in. In order to do collision detection I wrote a method that takes a **cardinal direction**, the players current **collision box**, and a **distance** which is usually their speed.
The **cardinal direction** is an enum that has methods for the adjX and adjY.
For example; **East** would return *adjX() = 1* and *adjY() = 0* whereas
**SouthEast** would return *adjX() = 1* and *adjY() = 1* <-- Positive because this is the movement in a 2D array.

**The Collision Check**

```
public int canMove(Direction dir, Rectangle collisionBox, int distance) {       
    int goodToGo = 0;
    // Check each 'step' of our attempted movement from 1 - distance(ie speed)
    for(int i = 1; i <= distance; i++) {
        // Assemble suggested new position bounds to check, ie corners of suggested movement    
        HashSet<Vector2f> cornerPoints = new HashSet<Vector2f>();
        cornerPoints.add( new Vector2f(collisionBox.getMinX()+dir.adjX()*i, collisionBox.getMinY()+dir.adjY()*i) );
        cornerPoints.add( new Vector2f(collisionBox.getMaxX()+dir.adjX()*i, collisionBox.getMinY()+dir.adjY()*i) );
        cornerPoints.add( new Vector2f(collisionBox.getMinX()+dir.adjX()*i, collisionBox.getMaxY()+dir.adjY()*i) );
        cornerPoints.add( new Vector2f(collisionBox.getMaxX()+dir.adjX()*i, collisionBox.getMaxY()+dir.adjY()*i) );

        // Check each corner of this step
        for( Vector2f point : cornerPoints ) {
            // Out of bounds check
            if( point.y < 0 || point.y > this.dungeonHeight*ratioRow ||
                    point.x < 0 || point.x > this.dungeonWidth*ratioCol ) {
                return goodToGo;
            }

            // Figure out what map square this point falls on
            int checkX = (int) (point.x / ratioCol);
            int checkY = (int) (point.y / ratioRow);

            // If that's a wall square... no go, we're done here, return the number of steps that
            // were OKed so far
            if( this.dungeon[checkY][checkX].getTileLetter('W') ) {
                return goodToGo;
            }
        }
        // If this step, i, didn't have any conflicts on any of the proposed new corners, then
        // increment our ongoing count of how many steps are OK to take
        goodToGo++;
    }
    return goodToGo;
}
```

I know blocks of code are kind of a bitch but any feedback or just shared attempts at 2D collision detection in Slick/Java are very appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

That really looks quite slow.

First of, don't use HashSet in these situations. A HashSet is a HashMap with "blind" values - like using the key as a value, too. They guarantee uniqueness and fast access (as everyone knows!), but for a set of **four objects** in a tight and often called loop, you are really hurting performance - the creation overhead is far too high and lookup speed isn't that great.

Next, you should probably change your usage pattern. Don't store distances in `int` if everything else is `float`. Same goes the other way around - the conversion between `int` and `float` is not free and you should avoid it in code that has to be really fast.

It looks like you never use fractional values and always integers - even in your floats - so you probaly think you can get away with them. They are used as painting positions for the tiles anyway.

Still, even for pixel-precise games, as soon as you change to float, everything starts to get smoother. Because you get sub-pixel movements, which wouldn't be possible for `int`. You can't display them, but they still affect percieved smoothness. I'd go for float, always keep positional data as floats and only convert to int when I need it to draw stuff.

Next, you can use a vastly better collision check method.

Vastly better in most cases as least. If every object is rectangular, you'd be ok with your way - but there's a lot of conditionals involved and you end up with code like this:

`if (!(a.maxY < b.minY || a.minY > b.maxY)) blocked = true;` ....

The other (better) way:

Use bounding circles. For each object, you store `float x, y, boundsRadius;` - the center and the distance to the entities point with the largest distance from the center.

Then... pythagoras (a*a + b*b = c*c)! For entities `e1` and `e2`:

```
public static boolean maybeCollision(Entity e1, Entity e2) {
    float xDistance = e1.x - e2.x,
          yDistance = e1.y - e2.y,
          rSum      = e1.boundsRadius + e2.boundsRadius
    ;
    return xDistance * xDistance + yDistance * yDistance < rSum * rSum;
}
```

It's like calculating the distance - `Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy)` - but we don't use square root (which is on the slow side) and square the sum of the radius instead. You can use `float` or `int` - it doesn't matter as long as there is no overflow. Just change the local variables.

I really love how it's totally independend of the orientation of the objects towards each other - you don't need any `if`s, the square of the distance automatically makes the result positive and it just works.

Here, I call the method `maybeCollision` (and that's a bad name, as it's not a verb. Still fits!) because you still have to check per pixel - it sees anything inside of the circle as a collision. But it's lightning fast and you have to check with bounding boxes, too (as long as you don't write Tetris or a round-based Minecraft)...